# Best placement for filtering and sorting options?

Tags: layout, search, user-research, filter, sorting

filtering & sorting options are generally placed top right corner of search results page. My understanding is that this frees vital page space need for results tagline ( describing what search results are being displayed). However, I have also came across designs that place filtering sorting options in the top left corner of the search results page. So I was wondering if there is any research to support either of these placements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The filtering options are placed top corner, horizontally side by side (usually left) when there are only few facets and facet values to show. Sorting options are placed more often right.

There are also cases where filters are stacked on top of each other on the left and search results on the right (most typical layout). It is usually the best choice when there are many facets and many values in each facet.

An example with all the above cases

[image]

[Designing Search: UX Strategies for eCommerce Success](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470942231.html) is a reference for search methods and search results in ecommerce but also in general

Comment: What about mobile?